# How to set Images(Uri) to listview using picasso in android

Tags: android, listview

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aa, container, false);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getActivity());
    Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL); 

title1=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.posttitle);
    description1=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postdesc);
    image1=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postimage);


    final List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
// Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = {"title", "desc", "name"};
    int[] to = {R.id.posttitle, R.id.postdesc, R.id.postdate};
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList, R.layout.layoutarray, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot single : child.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) single.getValue();

                    namerc = (String) map.get("Namerc");
                    String image = (String) map.get("Imagerc");//IMAGE URI
                    description = (String) map.get("Description");
                    title=(String) map.get("Title");

                    if (namerc!=null && description!=null && title!=null) {
                        String[] title1={title};
                        String[] desc1={description};
                        String[] name1={namerc};

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        for (int i=0;i<title1.length;i++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("title", title1[i]);
                            hm.put("desc", desc1[i]);
                            hm.put("name", name1[i]);
                            aList.add(0,hm);
                        }
                        // Keys used in Hashmap

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

This is my code here i am geting values and setting it to listview but i couldnt set image to listview .how can i set it please help me.
how to set image uri to listview,here i am getting uri from database?

Comment: try this<https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/>.

Comment: post your adapter class where you inflate the children.

Comment: i dont have any adapter class buddy,in this class only i inflate chidren

Comment: i have updated the code buddy check it..

Comment: bansal the link yu gave is not valid

Comment: create one imageview inside list view and use this to load image in it. Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);

Comment: @Prakash Bala how to do it inside listview pls can yu gv an example code?

Comment: This link has an example of recycler view with static image resources and Glide image library, please understand the code, u can change it to dynamic link and Picasso library.  http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/ NOTE: Better use recycler view than list view.

Comment: i want when user click on list view it should take to the new activity,is it possible in recyclerview?

Comment: To stick with your existing code, either subclass `SimpleAdapter` or attach a `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder` to it, where your binding code uses Picasso.

Comment: can yu give me example code to use simple adapter for existing code pls..

Comment: Create a adpater Class extends with simpleAdapter and use image "Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView); " in getView method

Comment: how to create an adapter class pls give some idea buddy..

Answer (score 0):

In getView method of adapter you can set image same as other data like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

you can pass url or uri in .load()

You can create adapter by following this tutorial :
[listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: I dont hv getView method in myadapter class buddy.how to do it all i hv done in same class

Comment: @Shivuday if you want to use multiple widgets with list then you have to create your adapter.

Comment: How to create an adapter for my class pls help me

Comment: @Shivuday check my edited answer and follow that tutorial for listview. I suggest you to use RecyclerView.

Comment: i am not understanding buddy,how can i edit this code to adapter

Comment: You have to create your own adapter and pass list to it. You have to read some tutorials and understand the code.

Comment: Yes create adapter and pass your data to it and look into tutorial for guidance